# How to report trailhead bugs

Tags: error, trailhead

Is there a way to report a bug in Salesforce Trailhead.
The third step of Security Superbadge definitely contains an error. When I click "Submit" button the page makes AJAX call which fails with 500 status code and "Submit" button hangs forever.

Answer (score 4):

The best places I have found for this are the [Developer Forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/#!/feedtype=RECENT&dc=Trailhead&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS) and the [Trailhead Success](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009Nek) community as these both have active involvement from the Trailhead team.

Comment: I just checked it out, and the error's been reported on the community already. That's a useful link to have.

Answer (score 3):

You can send a tweet to [@trailhead](https://twitter.com/trailhead), and they'll respond in a timely manner. They'll probably want to DM with you for more information. I recently reported a problem where the system would just hang and never validate a challenge, and they got back to me quickly.